# Selecting transactions based on Date Range

Tags: c#

I'm faced with an issue where my application is doing a search for transactions based on a FROM and TO date.

Lets use the following example:

> TRANS1: 14-Feb-2012 2:23:36
>
> TRANS2: 07-Feb-2012 3:23:47

My date ranges in C# is as follow:

> startDate.Date    {7/02/2012 12:00:00 AM}
>
> endDate.Date  {14/02/2012 12:00:00 AM}

The following line of code will ALWAYS exclude transactions if they fall on the endDate because the endDate is always set to 12:00:00AM (Based on DateTime.Now)

```
if (trans.TransactionDate >= startDate.Date &&
                                   trans.TransactionDate <= endDate.Date)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

How do I correctly handle this so that it includes all transactions for the 14th as well? Is it safe to do the following:

Changing 12:00:00AM to 12:00:00PM

```
if (trans.TransactionDate >= startDate.Date && 
                     trans.TransactionDate <= endDate.Date.AddHours(12))
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: `endDate.Date.AddHours(12)` will include transactions until noon on that day... probably not what you want. Try `endDate.Date.AddDays(1.0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work:

```
if (trans.TransactionDate.Date >= startDate.Date && trans.TransactionDate.Date <= endDate.Date)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a better solution.